# Irrationality of an "Euler-like" number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of zeroes and ones such that $a_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Let $\displaystyle x:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} .$

Is $x$ irrational? I believe it is, but I don't know how to prove it. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I think [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#Fourier's_proof) for the irrationality of $e$ should also work here, just change $\frac{1}{n!}$ to $\frac{a_n}{n!}$

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: OK, next prove it is transcendental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out by leoli1, this problem can be easily solved by slightly modifying Fourier's proof of irrationality of Euler's number.

Case closed.